# RegEx : Find match based on 1st two chars

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to RegEx and thus have a question on RegEx. I am writing my code in C# and need to come up with a regex to find matching strings.

The possible combination of strings i get are,

```
XYZF44DT508755
ABZF44DT508755
PQZF44DT508755
```

So what i need to check is whether the string starts with XY or AB or PQ.

I came up with this one and it doesn't work.

```
^((XY|AB|PQ).){2}
```

**Note: I don't want to use regular string StartsWith()**

**UPDATE:**

Now if i want to try a new matching condition like this -

```
If string starts with "XY" or "AB" or "PQ" and 3rd character is "Z" and 4th character is "F"
```

How to write the RegEx for that?

Comment: How did you come up with `.` and `{2}`? (What do you think those mean?) It sounds like you're trying to modify an existing regex without understanding it. I recommend that you simply read through a regex tutorial/introduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to test for just `^(XY|AB|PQ)`. Your RegEx means: Search for either XY, AB or PQ, then a random character, and repeat the whole sequence twice, for example "XYKPQL" would match your RegEx.

This is a screenshot of the matches on [regex101](https://regex101.com/):

[image: regex matches]

`^` forces the start of line,
`(...)` creates a matching group and
`XY|AB|PQ` matches either XY, AB or PQ.

If you want the next two characters to be ZF, just append ZF to the RegEx so it becomes `^(XY|AB|PQ)ZF`.

Check out [regex101](https://regex101.com/), a great way to test your RegExes.

Comment: Please see UPDATE to my original question

Answer (score 3):

You can modify you expression to the following and use the [`IsMatch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, "^(?:XY|AB|PQ)")
```

The outer capturing group in conjuction with `.` (*any single character*) is trying to match a third character and then repeat the sequence twice because of the range quantifier `{2}` ...

According to your updated edit, you can simply place "ZF" after the grouping construct.

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, "^(?:XY|AB|PQ)ZF")
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. `^(XY|AB|PQ)` should match your string correctly.

The problem with `^((XY|AB|PQ).){2}` is following the entire group with `{2}`. This means *exactly 2 occurrences*. That would be 2 occurrences of your first 2 characters, plus `.` (any single character), meaning this would match strings like `XY_AB_`. The `_` could be anything.

It may have been your intention with the `.` to match a larger string. In this case you might try something along the lines of `^((XY|AB|PQ)\w*)`. The `\w*` will match 0 or more occurrences of "word characters", so this should match all of `XYZF44DT508755` up to a space, line break, punctuation, etc., and not just the `XY` at the beginning.

There are some good tools out there for understanding regexes, one of my favorites is [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/).

## UPDATE

To answer your updated question:

> If string starts with "XY" or "AB" or "PQ" and 3rd character is "Z" and 4th character is "F"

The regex would be (assuming you want to match the entire "word").
    ^((XY|AB|PQ)ZF\w*)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SffBQQHpM1MLO2TI)